# json string not being parsed correctly

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with a Rest Api. I send the username and password when the user clicks on login from an MVC App but I keep getting back error

> 400 Bad Request

Now I've debugged through the code and realized the string being parsed to the api is as follows

```
"{\"username\":\"email@somedomain.com\",\"password\":\"mypassword\"}"
```

So I decided to remove the `\` from the string as follows:

```
string jsonString = JsonString(model.Email, model.Password);
string data = jsonString.Replace(@"\", "");
```

But for whatever reason the back slashes are not being removed :/ The string should be parsed as:

```
{"username":"email@somedomain.com","password":"mypassword"}
```

Here is the full code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.BaseAddress = new Uri("myurl");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

string jsonString = JsonString(model.Email, model.Password);
string data = jsonString.Replace(@"\", "");

HttpContent content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage messge = client.PostAsync("api/Account/Login", content).Result;

 if (messge.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
 }
 else
 {
   ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
   return View(model);
 }
```

And the `JsonString` method is as follows:

```
private string UserString(string us, string ps)
{
   var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
     new
     {
        username = us,
        password = ps
     });

  return json;
}
```

api/Account/Login method looks like this

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Login")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(UserModel userModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    IdentityUser result = await _repo.FindUser(userModel.UserName, userModel.Password);

    return Ok();
}
```

And find FindUser method looks like this

```
public async Task<IdentityUser> FindUser(string userName, string password)
{
    IdentityUser user = await _userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);

    return user;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not removing the backslashes? Maybe it's just still failing because you left the double quotes on both ends.

Comment: @itsme86 Yes i've debuged it again and I can see it's not remove the backslashes

Comment: what does the REST Api look like,  are you sure it wants json?

Comment: @Fran I've updated the code and include the API code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove \ characters. It is escape character for special characters that cannot be normal part of strings, in this case " is character for begining and end of strings. When you need to use " inside string you have to insert \ before that. So that the result is \". See c# specs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx). The problem causing 400 is probably somewhere else. Can you provide your api/Account/Login method?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I have updated the question and included the api/Account/Login method

Comment: How does the UserModel class look like? Or you can try to use `client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Account/Login", model)` method instead.

Comment: UuserModel class has a few `prop` `Username, Password, Email`. Can you provide an example with `PostAsJsonAsync` Please?

Comment: I still get bad request with `PostAsJsonAsync`

Comment: Still the same problem, If I pass the string as `"{""username"":""email@somedomain.com"",""password"":""mypassword""}"` then it works

Comment: If you use PostAsJsonAsync there is no need to serialize model to json string. You should pass it as parameter directly.

Comment: I used the link you provided without any modification and that problem presist. I didn't serialize the json

Comment: PostAsJsonAsync<UserModel> will handle all the serialization for you.  it will also setup all the headers for you.  it will clear out a lot of code.  Also if you need to be camelcased, you can set the serializationformatter. see here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fc50fcb0-b3e9-41a0-9e42-b33425181d0d/httpclientextensionspostasjsonasync-change-json-serializer-settings?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: @Fran Would it be possible if you can provide an example please

Answer (score 0):

you can probably strip out a lot of code here.

```
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("<your full url>", new UserModel { Email = "whatever", Password = "password" });
    }
```

PostAsJsonAsync will handle serializing the model, and setting up the http call.

PostAsJsonAsync is part of the Web Api Client Nuget package.

I would also set a breakpoint in the Login method to find out exactly what model error is the Login method.